# Making Monthly Transaction

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I need help on how to make this code below be executed on a monthly basis in Visual Basic 2010 using Ms Access. I tried to set a monthly date but I  could only set for a specific month. I want it to be like a banking system where its executed every monthend.

```
Public Sub Withdraw

    If myConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        myConnection.Open()
    End If

    str = "insert into [Transactions] ([TransactionID],[EmployeeID], [AccountNumber], [TransDate], [Description], [Debit], [Balance], [Time]) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("TransactionID", CType(TNumber, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("EmployeeID", CType(OveralEmployeeID, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("AccountNumber", CType(AccountNumberTextBox.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("TransDate", CType(CurrentDate, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Description", CType("Withdraw     WD - " + TNumber, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Debit", CType(WithdrawAmountTextBox.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Balance", CType(GetBalance(), String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Time", CType(CurrentTime, String)))
          Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        myConnection.Close()
        ClearGroupBox()
        AccountNumberTextBox.Text = Nothing
        MsgBox("Withdraw Reorded")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You want to execute this command once per month? Why don't you [Schedule A Task](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx)?

Comment: that's exactly what am looking for. I cant seen to find it. Help on scheduling a task

Comment: Then this is not a programming question. Did you take a look at the link I provided?

Comment: I had not noticed the link. I followed the link but discovered that its for Windows Server. Will it still work for Visual Basics?

Comment: Let me be clear. This is **NOT** a programming question. Compile your code. Schedule it to be executed by Windows using a Scheduled Task.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But is there any other way to address my problem. Am making a system that keeps bank records (deposits and withdraws) Is there another way I could let bank charges get deducted automatically at last day of the month.

Comment: I suggest you look into creating a service rather than console app and keeping track of time in your application, perhaps with an event. Do reach, attempt some code, and ask questions here once you have tried something.